# Android Activity Title Waiting spin

Tags: android, busyindicator

In the Activity title bar, how do I put a spinning wait in the upper right corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` on your `Activity`.